# jQuery ajax mysql select doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla, joomla2.5

Hello I'm trying to do a mysql query with ajax based on two select options in a joomla component I'm working on.

I don't want to post the whole HTML so I shortend it. I checked the values are passed trough to the php but I get nothing in return.

So this is the php and the js:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- load necessary files here -->
</head>
<?php
function firstQuery(){
 if(isset($_POST['adr'])){
  $one = $_POST['adr']; //adr is the name of the first select
  $two = $_POST['toadr']; //toadr is the name of the second select

  $db = JFactory::getDbo();
  $query = $db->getQuery(true);
  $query->select(array('range', 'time', 'cost'));
  $query->from('#__transfer_rang');
  $query->where('from="'.$one.'" AND to="'.$two.'"');
  $db->setQuery($query);
  $results = $db->loadObjectList();

  print_r($results);
  exit;
 }
}

firstQuery();
?>

<body>
<script>
$(function=(){
 $("#click").click(function () {
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: $("#myform").serialize(),
   success: function(data){
    $('#test').html(data);
   }
  });
 });
});

</script>

<div id="test">
</div>
<form id="myform" method="post" action=""><!-- form stuff here --></form>
</body>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Where is your `url: ....` - `$.ajax({ url: ..., type: "POST", ... });`? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Just realized that there is alternate syntax - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings - that allows the `url` to be blank, with the default being the current page. So disregard the previous comment, unless your php code is not on the same page.

Comment: I left the URL out because I'm posting the data into the same file and if I simply echo out `$one` and `$two` than it shows me the value of the selected option so I don't understand why shouldn't it work if do a query instead of echo

Comment: If your echo works, but not your query, it is possible that your query if failing/erring out. I am not familiar with `JFactory::getDbo();`, so I don't know what the standard error functions are. You could turn on php error reporting on to see what is happening - `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1); ?>`

Comment: Actually nothing happens if the error reporting is on. thats the frustrating about it. Now I changed the joomla specific db query to a simple mysqli fetch object but its the same nothing happens no error no result

Comment: Oh my GOD. there was missing an ` char(alt gr + 7) from the column names in the where. now its working like charm. I will write a bugreport to the joomla devs. because the joomla doc is faulty.

Comment: You have a strange syntax on the "onload": $(function=() should be $(function(); also you need to properly quote the strings: from="'.$one.'" should be from='.$db->quote($one).' and if you need backticks  ` let Joomla add them i.e. select('a.'.$db->quoteName('time') ...